# Windows Phone 8 Long List Selector - scroll to bottom after data loaded async

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await, longlistselector

I'm creating an app similar to the stock Messaging. But i'm very new to wp8 development and also to c# and .net

I'm using the Long List Selector to display messages. Messages are loaded on NavigatedTo event of the page. the handler is async as it is loading the data from a webservice, when there are 0 stored in local db, then it saves them in local database.

I would like to scroll to the last message after the data is loaded.

the page OnNavigated to

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string contactId = "";
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("contactId", out contactId))
    {
        await App.MessagesViewModel.LoadData();

        DataContext = App.MessagesViewModel;

        //scroll to last message, but it's apparently to soon
        var lastMessage = App.MessagesViewModel.Messages.LastOrDefault();
        llsMessages.ScrollTo(lastMessage);
    }
}
```

but this throws an exception System.ArgumentException: The provided item doesn't exist in the collection. So i figured the list hasn't yet changed.

So i tried different events of LongListSelector that would indicate that it has already added the data from the view model. After a while of experimetnation i came up with this

```
private void llsMessages_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var lastMessage = App.MessagesViewModel.Messages.LastOrDefault();
    if (lastMessage != null)
    {
        llsMessages.ScrollTo(lastMessage);
    }
}
```

but this works only when the messages are loaded from the database. When loading from webservice the last message is null.

So after load i'm on the first message at top, then i navigate away from the page, then come back, the list scrolls to bottom. i would like to eliminate this, but i have no idea how.

is there any way how to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe instead of looking at LLS SizeChanged, look at CollectionChanged and when the item is added, scroll the LLS.

Comment: i dont see that event in properties editor or in code. is it an event belonging to lls?

Comment: It's an event that your collection has (or should have) - App.MessagesVieModel.Messages.CollectionChanged. It's just my loose thinking, thought I've not tried this. Maybe other solution will be adding special item at the end to which you will jump when collection changes, but then you will have to insert item before the last instead of add.

Comment: i got it working when i add a new message. i need to jump to the end of the list after i load all messages from a web service asynchronously. the async thing is making it difficult

Comment: I don't know how your LoadData() looks like, but I've added an answer, maybe it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
private async Task DoAndScroll()
{
   await App.MessagesViewModel.LoadData();
   var lastMessage = App.MessagesViewModel.Messages.LastOrDefault();
   llsMessages.ScrollTo(lastMessage);
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   string contactId = "";
   if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("contactId", out contactId))
   {
      DataContext = App.MessagesViewModel;  
      DoAndScroll();     
   }
}
```

Comment: DoAndScroll waits for LoadData and then gets lastMessage and ScrollsTo(). It's also run asynchronously so it doesn't block your main UI. In your code OnNavigated was blocked with await LoadData(), but the MainCode which invoked OnNavigatedTo went on and probably caused Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try the ItemRealized event of the longlistselector. Check whether the currently processed item in the selector is the last item of your datacontext and if it is so, then scroll to that item. Below code worked for me.

```
private void longlist_ItemRealized(object sender, ItemRealizationEventArgs e)
    {
        Search.BindSearch search = e.Container.Content as Search.BindSearch;
        if (search != null)
        {
            int offset = 0;

            if (OCollectionBindSearch.Count - OCollectionBindSearch.IndexOf(search) <= offset)
            {
                longlist.ScrollTo(search);
            }                
        }
    }
```

Comment: but the when i scroll the list, i get many item realized events fired, wouldn't this slow down the ui?

Comment: It hasn't slowed my app yet, and I process my code only if it matches with the item I want.