# Determine when LongListSelector is Scrolling

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, converters, longlistselector

I would just simply like to be able to minimize the application bar when I am scrolling down, and then show its normal size when scrolling up. I've seen this ability on the facebook app and it seems very appealing and user friendly. I have my LongListSelector with items bound to it, and an appbar already in code behind. What is the missing key to enable such a feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to figure out when the user is scrolling and in what direction.  Here's a great article with example code.  [Detecting WP8 LongListSelector’s end of scroll](http://nuncaalaprimera.com/2013/detecting-wp8-longlistselectors-end-of-scroll-stretching/).  You can modify it to the point where it does exactly what you want.

However, if I was going do it,  I would take a more direct route.  I would derived my own LLS and attach a property to the value of the scrollbar.  Something like this :)

```C#
public class MyLLS : LongListSelector, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // implement the INotify
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {            
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        // dat grab doe
        sb = this.GetTemplateChild("VerticalScrollBar") as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollBar;
        sb.ValueChanged += sb_ValueChanged;           
    }

    void sb_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        // an animation has happen and they have moved a significance distance
        // set the new value
        ScrollValue = e.NewValue;

        // determine scroll direction
        if(e.NewValue > e.OldValue)
        {
            scroll_direction_down = true;
        }
        else
        {
            scroll_direction_down = false;
        }
    }

    public System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollBar sb;

    private bool scroll_direction_down = false;   // or whatever default you want

    public bool ScrollDirectionDown
    { get { return scroll_direction_down; } }

    public double ScrollValue
    {
        get
        {
            if (sb != null)
            {
                return sb.Value;
            }
            else
                return 0;
        }
        set
        {
            sb.Value = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ScrollValue");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Now you know the exact scroll position.  You can even get the top and bottom value by doing

```
double min = this.sb.Minimum;
double max = this.sb.Maximum;
```

Now bind that `ScrollDirectionDown` property to a converter to your AppBar visibility and you'll have your goals met.

---

If you can't bind then you have to do a callback to update the visibility.  But if you want something more simple just hook it up to the `ManipulationStateChanged` event of the custom LLS.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } 

    private void lls_ManipulationStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lls.ScrollDirectionDown)
        {
            ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
        }             
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I've implemented the custom LongListSelector, now my issue is with creating the app bar mode converter to either display minimized or regular sized appbar..

Comment: I've added code of an appbar mode converter I created. Since my appbar is in code behind how can I bind this in code behind to update the appbar mode while the longlistselector is being scrolled down?

Comment: You can't bind the regular AppBar, you can use third party bar with a more lax pattern (Caliburn.Micro).  In your case I would write a call back when the ScrollDirectionDown has changed to change the ApplicationBar visibility.  But for simplicity, I just going to add it to the `ManipulationStateChanged` change event on the custom LLS.  See updated solution.

Answer (score 0):

So for that you have to detect when the `longlistselector` starts scrolling. For that to achieve there's a similar thread here:

[Windows Phone 8 Long List Selector - scroll to bottom after data loaded async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900348/)

In the `DoAndScroll` method you could simply include the code to minimize the `AppBar`.

Within your xaml code of your appbar, change the mode to Minimized.

```
<shell:ApplicationBar Mode="Minimized" Opacity="1.0" IsMenuEnabled="True" IsVisible="True"></>
```

Thereafter whenever it scrolls back up, make the `Mode` of the `AppBar`to `Default`.

Or else have a look at this to detect the bottom of the `longlistselector`.

[Detecting WP8 LongListSelector’s end of scroll](http://nuncaalaprimera.com/2013/detecting-wp8-longlistselectors-end-of-scroll-stretching/)